# Extracting words with apostrophe as final possible letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following program extracting all the patterns (words with possible hyphens, punctuation marks)

```
sentence="Narrow-minded people are happy although it's cold ! I'm also happy" 
print(re.split('([^-\w])',sentence))
```

The result is :

```
['Narrow-minded', ' ', 'people', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'happy', ' ', 'although', ' ', 'it', "'", 's', ' ', 'cold', ' ', '', '!', '', ' ', 'I', "'", 'm', ' ', 'also', ' ', 'happy']
```

The question is how to consider (add) the apostrophe at end of a word. For example: we would like to retrieve `"it'"` instead of the couple `"it", "'"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add words ending with an apostrophe as a special case:

```
print(re.split('([\w-]+\'|[^-\w])',sentence))
```

in this case, the sentence is split on either

- a sequence of one or more `\w`-characters followed by an apostrophe (the `[\w-]+\'` part
- OR any character which is not a dash or a `\w`-character  (the `[^-\w]` part)

This results in:

```
['Narrow-minded', ' ', 'people', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'happy', ' ', 'although', ' ', '', "it'", 's', ' ', 'cold', ' ', '', '!', '', ' ', '', "I'", 'm', ' ', 'also', ' ', 'happy']
```

Note that this does increase the number of empty strings (`''`) in the list, to get rid of those you can filter the list:

```
print(filter(None, re.split('([\w-]+\'|[^-\w])',sentence)))
```

which results in:

```
['Narrow-minded', ' ', 'people', ' ', 'are', ' ', 'happy', ' ', 'although', ' ', "it'", 's', ' ', 'cold', ' ', '!', ' ', "I'", 'm', ' ', 'also', ' ', 'happy']
```

Comment: Suprinsgly there is a little mistake, after the word 'although' there is ' ' and then '' instead of only ""

Comment: @Hana I have updated the answer to provide more details. Given that the original output already contained empty strings (`''`) around the exclamation mark I figured that it was not a problem to have more.

Comment: How could we improve your expression to put exceptions (two special words to which we do not want the re to be applied (e.g. O'Neill)